# How to get non null result from getValue() of mapped LiveData without calling observe()?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I'm using `Transformations.map` method to get a new `LiveData` based on original one. While `getValue` method of the original returns always a correct value, the same accessor of the mapped on returns `null`.

How can I solve or workaround this issue in order to test the class exposing `LiveData` without calling `observe` on it?

Here is the code explaining this problem:

```
public class LiveDataTest {

    @Rule
    public TestRule rule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

    @Test
    public void mapTest() {
        final MutableLiveData<String> original = new MutableLiveData<>();
        final LiveData<String> mapped = Transformations.map(original, input -> "Mapped: " + input);

        System.out.println(original.getValue()); // null - OK
        System.out.println(mapped.getValue()); // null - OK

        original.setValue("Hello, World!");

        System.out.println(original.getValue());  // "Hello, World!" - OK
        System.out.println(mapped.getValue()); // null - Should be "Mapped: Hello, World!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations:

> The transformations aren't calculated unless an observer is observing
>   the returned LiveData object.

So `mapped` has to be observed first.

To editted post: just call `mapped.observeForever();` passing in empty observer, before trying to get mapped value.

Comment: Thanks! After reading your answer I've rephrased the question - I'm looking for the workaround of this issue in order to perform tests without calling `observe`.

Comment: Updated my answer. It should be ok for tests.

Comment: Actually not using observer at all is not only not possible, but not recommended.
Here is some code from my tests (in kotlin, but idea should be clear):
```val sweetsRatingObserver: Observer<Map<SweetRating, Long>> = mock()
        viewModel.sweetsRatingData.observeForever(sweetsRatingObserver)
        then(sweetsRatingObserver).should().onChanged(sweetsRating) ```
where sweetsRating is expected value. I believe it is most appropriate to test the change too as LiveData's getValue() should not be the main using point.